# Flutter secure storage test

Tags: flutter, testing, storage

Good day!
I need to test some functions from flutter secure storage. For example `storage.saveAccessToken`

I have made MockFlutterStorage to emulate a save in a storage, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
@GenerateMocks([mockFlutterSecureStorage.FlutterSecureStorage])
void main() {
  group('#accessToken', () {
    test('Save accessToken in a storage', () async {
      final mockFlutterSecureStorage = MockFlutterSecureStorage();

      String accessToken = 'a1';

      final storage = SecureStorage();

      when(mockFlutterSecureStorage.write(
              key: 'accessToken', value: accessToken))
          .thenAnswer((value) async => {
await storage.saveAccessToken(accessToken);

});
      

      expect(storage.accessToken, 'a1');
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello, mock are using to emulate some behavior. You cant check saving in this case, because you mocked and it no sence. Its external plugin. So all that you need to check is executin methods of plugin in your code using verify and nothing else.

Comment: So I just have to write verify(mockFlutterStorage.write(key: accessToken, value: accessToken)).called(1); ? in this case this function is called 0 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should add new answer to put an example. Note, that i am using [mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail). To explain the idea i think its enough

user_secure_data_source.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter_app/core/error/exception.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/features/auth/data/models/models.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

abstract class UserSecureDataSource {
  Future<AccessTokenModel> getSavedAccessToken();
  void saveAccessToken(AccessTokenModel accessToken);
}

const savedToken = 'SAVED_TOKEN';

class UserSecureDataSourceImpl implements UserSecureDataSource {
  UserSecureDataSourceImpl({required this.secureStorage});

  final FlutterSecureStorage secureStorage;

  @override
  Future<AccessTokenModel> getSavedAccessToken() async {
    final jsonString = await secureStorage.read(key: savedToken);
    if (jsonString != null) {
      return Future.value(AccessTokenModel.fromJson(json.decode(jsonString)));
    } else {
      throw NotFoundSavedTokenSecureException();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> saveAccessToken(AccessTokenModel accessToken) async {
    return secureStorage.write(
        key: savedToken, value: json.encode(accessToken));
  }
}
```

user_secure_data_source_test.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter_app/core/error/exception.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/features/auth/data/datasources/user_secure_data_source.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/features/auth/data/models/models.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

import '../../../../fixtures/fixtures_reader.dart';

class MockFlutterSecureStorage extends Mock implements FlutterSecureStorage {}

void main() {
  late UserSecureDataSourceImpl dataSource;
  late MockFlutterSecureStorage mockSecureStorage;
  final tAccessToken = AccessTokenModel.fromJson(
      json.decode(fixture('access_token_model.json')));

  setUp(() {
    mockSecureStorage = MockFlutterSecureStorage();
    dataSource = UserSecureDataSourceImpl(secureStorage: mockSecureStorage);
  });

  group('UserSecureDataSourceIml', () {
    group('getSavedAccessToken', () {
      test(
          'should return AccessTokenModel from FlutterSecureStorage when there is one the saved',
          () async {
        // arrange
        when(() => mockSecureStorage.read(key: savedToken))
            .thenAnswer((_) async => fixture('access_token_model.json'));

        // act
        final result = await dataSource.getSavedAccessToken();

        //assert
        verify(() => mockSecureStorage.read(key: savedToken));
        expect(result, equals(tAccessToken));
      });

      test(
          'should throw a NotFoundSavedTokenSecureException when is not saved token',
          () async {
        // arrange
        when(() => mockSecureStorage.read(key: savedToken))
            .thenAnswer((_) async => null);

        // act
        final call = dataSource.getSavedAccessToken;

        //assert
        expect(() => call(), throwsA(isA<NotFoundSavedTokenSecureException>()));
      });
    });

    group('saveAccessToken', () {
      test('should call FlutterSecureStorage to save token', () async {
        // arrange
        when(() =>
            mockSecureStorage.write(
                key: savedToken, value: json.encode(tAccessToken))).thenAnswer(
            (invocation) => Future<void>.value());

        //act
        dataSource.saveAccessToken(tAccessToken);

        // assert
        final expectedJsonString = json.encode(tAccessToken.toJson());
        verify(() => mockSecureStorage.write(
            key: savedToken, value: expectedJsonString));
      });
    });
  });
}
```

fixtures_reader.dart

```
import 'dart:io';

String fixture(String name) => File('test/fixtures/$name').readAsStringSync();
```

Comment: Thank you! I have managed it as well on weekend. But your version is more professional!

Comment: I tried, but i dont have a premission till now..need some higher level:(